# An object reference is required for the non-static field Ebay oauth library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ebay-api

So I have referenced the ebay.oauth.client library and I'm trying to use it to get the access token but it's giving me an error.

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'OAuth2Api.GetApplicationToken(OAuthEnvironment, IList)

Here is my code

```
private string GetAuthTokenEbay()
        {
            bool isTestSite = true;
            var url = (isTestSite) ? "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com" : "https://api.ebay.com"
            var oAuthToken = "";
            CredentialUtil.Load("config.yaml");
            IList<String> scopes = new List<String>()
            {
                url + "/oauth/api_scope/buy.marketing",
                url + "/oauth/api_scope",
                url + "/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory.readonly",
                url + "/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory"
            };
            //String state = "current-page";
            OAuthEnvironment env = (isTestSite) ? OAuthEnvironment.SANDBOX : OAuthEnvironment.PRODUCTION;
            oAuthToken = OAuth2Api.GetApplicationToken(env, scopes).AccessToken;

            return oAuthToken;
        }
```

Comment: Also I downloaded the solution from github and built it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, at the top of my class I needed the static oauthapi like so:

```
private static OAuth2Api api;
```

then I needed to get the application token like so

```
oAuthToken = api.GetApplicationToken(env, scopes).AccessToken.Token;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to help all users of this kind of problem, it is useful to give the code as below originating from yours...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using eBay.ApiClient.Auth.OAuth2;
using eBay.ApiClient.Auth.OAuth2.Model;
private static OAuth2Api api = new OAuth2Api();
private string GetAuthTokenEbay()
{
    bool isTestSite = true;
    var url = (isTestSite) ? "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com" : "https://api.ebay.com";
    var oAuthToken = "";
    CredentialUtil.Load("config.yaml");
    IList<String> scopes = new List<String>()
    {
        url + "/oauth/api_scope/buy.marketing",
        url + "/oauth/api_scope",
        url + "/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory.readonly",
        url + "/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory"
    };
    //String state = "current-page";
    OAuthEnvironment env = (isTestSite) ? OAuthEnvironment.SANDBOX : OAuthEnvironment.PRODUCTION;
    oAuthToken = api.GetApplicationToken(env, scopes).AccessToken.Token;
    return oAuthToken;
}
```